# ARKit place models in the real world randomly

Tags: ios, swift3, arkit

I'm experimenting with ARKit and I'm trying to place some models around the user. So what I want is that when the app starts it just places some models around the user so He needs to find them.

When he moves like for example 10 meters I want to add some random models again. I thought I could do it this way:

```
 let cameraTransform = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform
        let cameraCoordinates = MDLTransform(matrix: cameraTransform!)

        let camX = CGFloat(cameraCoordinates.translation.x)
        let camY = CGFloat(cameraCoordinates.translation.y)
        let cameraPosition = CGPoint(x: camX, y: camY)
        let anchors = self.sceneView.hitTest(cameraPosition, types: [.featurePoint, .estimatedHorizontalPlane])

        if let hit = anchors.first {
            let hitTransform = SCNMatrix4(hit.worldTransform)
            let hitPosition = SCNVector3Make(hitTransform.m41, hitTransform.m42, hitTransform.m43)
            self.sceneView.session.add(anchor: ARAnchor(transform: hit.worldTransform))
            return Coordinate(hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y, hitPosition.z)
        }

        return Coordinate(0, 0, 0)
    }
```

The problem is sometimes it doesn't find any anchors and then I don't know what to do. And when it finds some anchors it is randomly placed behind me not in front of me but behind me. I don't know why because never turn the camera so it can't find any anchors.

Is there a better way to place random models in the real world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it you'll need use [session(_:didUpdate:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session) delegate method:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    guard let cameraTransform = session.currentFrame?.camera.transform else { return }
    let cameraPosition = SCNVector3(
        /* At this moment you could be sure, that camera properly oriented in world coordinates */
        cameraTransform.columns.3.x,
        cameraTransform.columns.3.y,
        cameraTransform.columns.3.z
    )
    /* Now you have cameraPosition with x,y,z coordinates and you can calculate distance between those to points */
    let randomPoint = CGPoint(
        /* Here you can make random point for hitTest. */
        x: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
        y: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    )
    guard let testResult = frame.hitTest(randomPoint, types: .featurePoint).first else { return }
    let objectPoint = SCNVector3(
        /* Converting 4x4 matrix into x,y,z point */
        testResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x,
        testResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y,
        testResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z
    )
    /* do whatever you need with this object point */
}
```

It'll allows you place object whenever camera position updates:

> Implement this method if you provide your own display for rendering an
>   AR experience. The provided ARFrame object contains the latest image
>   captured from the device camera, which you can render as a scene
>   background, as well as information about camera parameters and anchor
>   transforms you can use for rendering virtual content on top of the
>   camera image.

Really **important** here, that you're randomly choosing point for `hitTest` method, and this point always will be in front of camera.

Don't forget to use from 0 to 1.0 coordinate system for CGPoint in [hitTest method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2875718-hittest):

> A point in normalized image coordinate space. (The point (0,0)
>   represents the top left corner of the image, and the point (1,1)
>   represents the bottom right corner.)

If you want to place object each 10 meters, you can save camera position (in `session(_:didUpdate:)` method) and check that `x+z` coordinates was changed for far enough, to place new object.

**NOTE:**

I'm assuming that you're using world tracking session:

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have some questions. The point for hittesting in your example code the arcRandom should be some number between 0 and 1 you say so the point is always in front of the camera? And then the x+z coordinates to see if the user has moved enough. With what coordinates do I need to compare these? Is that the session.currentFrame?.camera.transform x and z?

Comment: @user1007522 Yes, `frame: ARFrame` from function parameters is always in front of camera. For comparing distance, use `cameraPosition`(see updated answer ^) .

Comment: Hey @Vasilii, thank you so much for your detailed answers! I and my team stuck on an issue for days ah :/ I posted an interesting question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662318/arkit-apply-filter-cifilter-to-a-specific-part-vertex-of-an-arfaceanchor Would love your suggestions!